# Can all acids be classified as a Lewis acid?

Tags: acid-base

There are three definitions of an *acid* that I am familiar with: Arrhenius acids, Brønsted–Lowry acids, and Lewis acids. From left to right, each new definition of an acid is broadened to include a wider variety of chemical species.

**If a Lewis acid is the broadest category of acids, which necessarily includes all Arrhenius acids and Brønsted–Lowry acids, can all acids be considered a Lewis acid?**

Comment: Logically the answer to your question can only be a robust yes

Comment: @Alchimista And of course, by extension, all bases are Lewis bases?

Comment: @Alchimista OP would need to start with true statement. The answer is **no** and questions lacks research. Broadest definition is Usanovitch's, and Lewis acids don't include Brønsted acids, which are adducts, by Lewis definition.

Comment: @Mithoron Interesting, I was not aware of Usanovitch's definition. So a Lewis definition is not the broadest. And indeed, not all lewis acids include Bronsted acids. According to Wikipedia, "A Lewis base is also a Brønsted–Lowry base, but a Lewis acid doesn't need to be a Brønsted–Lowry acid." I should have been more careful. Also, would it be fair to say that all Lewis bases are Bronsted bases?

Comment: With bases, it's technically true that one equals another, but in practice not necessarily. Also it's more correct that things *act* as acid or base then *are*.

Comment: @Mithoron I know. That was the point. There was actually no question. Yes I could have said that the "if" isn't satisfied. Perhaps I've been not very correct with OP but I was sure that this would have emerged.